# How can I get istanbul working with node, mocha, jasmine and require js

Tags: node.js, requirejs, jasmine, mocha.js, istanbul

I have an existing test suite that runs fine in node.js using mocha, require and jasmine, with the tests being run via a psake powershell script. I am attempting to add test coverage, so to run the unit test instead of doing:

node unitTest.js

I am doing

istanbul cover unitTest.js

Which seems to work but only gives me coverage information on the unitTest.js itself but not any of the other actual javascript files in use in the project. I'm guessing that is because of the require/mocha combination so it doesn't know about the js files I am using.

I tried manually instrumenting all the files as a step before the code coverage and running the same command on the copied/instrumented files but got the same result. Any tips on making this work?

Here is the last part of unitTest.js

```
    requirejs(['mocha'], function(Mocha) {
var mocha = new Mocha({reporter: (process.env['TEAMCITY_VERSION'] ? 'teamcity' : 'spec')});
// Hack to establish the global variables (sigh)
mocha.suite.emit('pre-require', global, __filename, mocha);

fswalk(__dirname, function(err, results) {
    if (err)
        console.warn(err);
    else {
        var testName = process.argv[2] || "";
        console.log("testName: " + testName);
        var inclusionSuffixes = [testName + '.test.js'];
        var exclusionSuffixes = ['.integration.test.js'];
        var tests = _.filter(results, function (result) {
            var test = function (suffix) { return result.indexOf(suffix) == result.length - suffix.length; };
            return _.any(inclusionSuffixes, test) && !_.any(exclusionSuffixes, test);
        });
        requirejs(tests, function () {
            mocha.run(function(failures) {
                process.exit(failures);
            });
        });
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Using the parameter --hook-run-in-context makes it work properly

Comment: Can you please make it an answer?

Answer (score 0):

@user2576666 answered the question in the comments:

"Using the parameter --hook-run-in-context makes it work properly"

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to trying to coax these various pieces to work together yourself is to use [Intern](https://github.com/theintern/intern).

This makes sense especially for projects using AMD (require.js). It uses Istanbul under the hood and has a proxy server that instruments your code automatically. It is a very slick set up for what you are trying to do.